# Programmatically add constraints to labels that have been programmatically added to a table cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, nslayoutconstraint

Here's what I've tried.

I've set my rows to automatically resize based on their content which works perfectly if I manually add labels and manually add constraints to said labels.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
}
```

Then I'm adding labels and their constraints like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TypeCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // Programmatically add a label
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = dataLabels[indexPath.row] // dataLabels is an array of my labels
    label.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.contentView.addSubview(label)

    // Programmatically add constraints
    label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

    return cell
}
```

When I run the project, I don't get any errors. The rows seem to be sizing to the height of the label and the label is responding to the programmatically set constraint but the row doesn't seem to know that the constraint exists. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

In my past experience, this should have been all that I needed to add constraints to objects programmatically.

I've also tried using:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

But that doesn't help. When the table reloads, it reloads right back to the same position.

Comment: let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.view, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
let bottomConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.view, attribute: .bottomMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 16)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint, bottomConstraint])
try this

Comment: `cell` has 4 `subviews` (the `contentView`, the 2 separator views, and the `UILabel`) so simply calling `view` wouldn't access anything specific. Nevertheless, I tried it and I get an error saying: `UITableViewCell` has no member `view`

Comment: Sorry is contentView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a common "whoops" mistake...

```
// Programmatically add constraints
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
```

What those two lines say, is:

- Make the Top of the Label equal to the Top of the ContentView PLUS 15pts.

then

- Make the Bottom of the Label equal to the Bottom of the ContentView PLUS 15pts.

What you *really* want is for the Bottom of the **ContentView** to be equal to the Bottom of the **Label** PLUS 15pts.

So, you can change the line to either:

```
// set Bottom of Label to Bottom of View MINUS 15pts
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
```

or

```
// set Bottom of View to Bottom of Label PLUS 15pts
cell.contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.bottomAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
```

That should do it.

Comment: Damnit, you were right, definitely a "whoops". Thank you!